# Is it possible to start with 3 Edges at character creation?

Tags: character-creation, savage-worlds

The manual says that you can "buy" points with Hindrances to take Edges or other bonuses.

At **Novice** level, is it possible to start with 3 Edges?

1. First Edge granted from Human race
2. Second Edge from one Major Hindrance
3. Third Edge from two Minor Hindrances

Or can you take only one Edge from Hindrances at character creation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct. The section on *Edges & Hindrances* in the Character Creation chapter indicates:

> You can take one Major Hindrance and two Minor Hindrances. A Major Hindrance is worth 2 points, and a Minor Hindrance is worth 1 point.
>
> For 2 points you can:
>
> - Gain another attribute point, or
> - **Choose an Edge**

So, if you take your maximum number of Hindrances you get 4 points, and this allows you to choose two separate Edges.

If you start as a human, you also get a free Edge on character creation, so the maximum number of Edges you can start with as a human is three (unless you take the Blind Hindrance, which gives you one more free Edge due to its severity).

Answer (score 1):

You can take 3, just like the way you list.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and review the [help] to get a feel for how this site works.  Your answer would be more helpful if you provide supporting references or rationale/support.  Happy Gaming! :-)